# Can anyone help me in fetching JSON nested array in table content in angular?

Tags: json, angular, html-table

How should I use *ngfor and table display following data?
I tried but get confused.

```
  <tr *ngFor='let properties.property_detail of properties, let i=index'>
              <td>{{properties.property_detail.name}}</td>
```

for observable
and

```
return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8000/properties',
        {   "name":properties.property_detail.getName(),


{

  "properties":
  [
    {
      "property_details":
      {
        "name":"xyz",
        "email":"xyz@gmail.com",
        "mobile":1234567890,
        "id":2
      },
      "property_info":{
        "geo_lat":45.3556,
        "geo_long":13.6576756,
        "property_depth":200,
        "property_rating":4,
        "property_status":sold
      },
        "property_owner":{
          "name":"alex",
          "mobile":8765434568
          },
          "_id":"ftf5yfgty",
          "__v":0
          }
       ]
}
```

Comment: You should start by reading/watching some form of tutorial. Have you tried the tour of heroes in the angular docs?

Answer (score 1):

How `ngFor` works in angular:

```
    *ngFor='let <element> of <array>; let i=index'
```

then inside the loop you can access element properties like `<element>.name`

I agree with @Jota.Toledo. you should try the angular tour of heroes.

And solution to your problem:

```
    <tr *ngFor='let property of response.properties; let i=index'>
        <td>{{property.property_details.name}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: In order to improve the quality of your answer, please add some commentary about what this code does and how it solves the original question.